# Mapear array e incluir itens conforme ID utilizando MAP e FILTER

Tags: javascript, array

Possuo dois arrays:

O primeiro possui algumas questões, ex:

Array **questions**:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question": "Questão 1:",
        "essay_question": false,
        "value": "2.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "question": "Questão 2:",
        "essay_question": false,
        "value": "1.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "question": "Questão 3:",
        "essay_question": false,
        "value": "1.00"
    }
]
```

E o segundo possui as opções de escolhas para as questões acima:

Array **options**:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "option": "Opção A",
        "correct": false,
        "question_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "option": "Opção B",
        "correct": true,
        "question_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "option": "Opção A",
        "correct": false,
        "question_id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "option": "Opção B",
        "correct": true,
        "question_id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "option": "Opção A",
        "correct": false,
        "question_id": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "option": "Opção B",
        "correct": true,
        "question_id": 4
    }
]
```

Preciso criar um novo array juntando estes dois da seguinte forma: Comparando o ID da questão com o id da opção e incluir as opções dentro do array de questão.

Ex:

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    question: 'Questão 1:',
    essay_question: false,
    value: '2.00',
    options: [
      {
        id: 1,
        option: 'Opção A',
        correct: false,
        question_id: 2,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        option: 'Opção B',
        correct: true,
        question_id: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

```
const questions = question.map((q) => {
  if (options.filter((opt) => opt.question_id === q.id))
    return { ...q.dataValues, options: opt.dataValues };
  return { ...q.dataValues, options: null };
});
```

O map e o filter funcionaram, o problema está na hora de colocar o array options encontrado dentro do array questions. Estou recebendo o erro: "'opt' is not defined."

Comment: O bloco do `if` em `if (options.filter((opt) => opt.question_id === q.id)) { ... }` sempre será executado pq o método `Array.prototype.filter` _sempre_ retorna um array (que é um valor _truthy_ em JavaScript, o que permite a entrada na condicional em questão). Além disso, você declarou `opt` como parâmetro do predicado passado ao `filter`, o que causa o erro posterior ao qual você se refere. O código, se corrigido, **[funciona](https://ideone.com/DuXTSc)**, embora possa contar com algumas melhorias para performance, já que atualmente tem complexidade `O(m * n)` sendo q poderia ser `O(m + n)`.

Comment: Entendi a questão do opt estar fora do escopo. Só não entendi a questão da complexidade O(M * n),

O código que vc sugeriu funcionou.

Comment: É porque para cada item de `questions`, você faz um `filter` em `options` por completo, isto é, varrerá o array `options` `n` vezes sendo `n` o número de elementos de `questions`. Desse modo, se `questions` tiver `m` elementos, você terá realizado `m * n` iterações! Tem como "melhorar" o código, tornando essa complexidade `m + n` utilizando um dicionário, embora isso implique em um custo de memória adicional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem também o algoritimo imperativo que vasculha primeiro o array `options` criando um catálogo `opts` cujo a chave é `options.question_id` e o valor é um array formado por referências aos elemento de `options` cujo a propriedade `question_id` seja o valor da chave.

Depois o algoritmo vasculha o array `question` pegando de `opts` os valores cujo a chave é `question.id`

```js
const question = [{
    "id": 2,
    "question": "Questão 1:",
    "essay_question": false,
    "value": "2.00"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "question": "Questão 2:",
    "essay_question": false,
    "value": "1.00"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "question": "Questão 3:",
    "essay_question": false,
    "value": "1.00"
  }
];

const options = [{
    "id": 1,
    "option": "Opção A",
    "correct": false,
    "question_id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "option": "Opção B",
    "correct": true,
    "question_id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "option": "Opção A",
    "correct": false,
    "question_id": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "option": "Opção B",
    "correct": true,
    "question_id": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "option": "Opção A",
    "correct": false,
    "question_id": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "option": "Opção B",
    "correct": true,
    "question_id": 4
  }
];

let opts = {};                     //O objeto será o catalogo. 

//Para cada elemento o de options...
for (let o of options) {
  //...verifica se o.question_id já foi catalogado...
  if (o.question_id in opts) {
    opts[o.question_id].push(o);   //...se sim, apenas adiciona o ao catalogo      
  } else {
    opts[o.question_id] = [o];     //...se não, cria uma chave o.question_id e adiciona um array preenchido com o como valor.
  }
}

//Para todos os elementos q de question...
for (let q of question) {
  //...verifica se q.id está no catálogo...
  if (q.id in opts) {
    q.options = opts[q.id];        //...se sim cria em que a propriedade options preenchida com os itens catalogados.
  }
}


console.log(question);
```

Answer (score 2):

O código é bem básico, faça um `map` para criar um novo `array` e em cada passagem dentro do `map` utilize `filter` no outro `array` buscando a informação de acordo com o filtro e passe as informações do filtro criando um nova chave `options`, ***exemplo***:

```
const questionWithOptions = question.map(x => {
  x.options = options.filter(c => c.question_id === x.id);
  return x;
});
```

***Completo:***

```js
const question = [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question": "Questão 1:",
        "essay_question": false,
        "value": "2.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "question": "Questão 2:",
        "essay_question": false,
        "value": "1.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "question": "Questão 3:",
        "essay_question": false,
        "value": "1.00"
    }
];

const options = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "option": "Opção A",
        "correct": false,
        "question_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "option": "Opção B",
        "correct": true,
        "question_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "option": "Opção A",
        "correct": false,
        "question_id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "option": "Opção B",
        "correct": true,
        "question_id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "option": "Opção A",
        "correct": false,
        "question_id": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "option": "Opção B",
        "correct": true,
        "question_id": 4
    }
];

const questionWithOptions = question.map(x => {
  x.options = options.filter(c => c.question_id === x.id);
  return x;
});

console.log(questionWithOptions);
```